# How to import a Python module from a sibling folder?

Tags: python, import, module, relative-path

I have gone through many Python relative import questions but I can't understand the issue/get it to work.

My directory structure is:

```
Driver.py

A/
      Account.py
      __init__.py

B/
      Test.py
      __init__.py
```

`Driver.py`

```
from B import Test
```

`Account.py`

```
class Account:
def __init__(self):
    self.money = 0
```

`Test.py`

```
from ..A import Account
```

When I try to run:

```
python Driver.py
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

from B import Test

File "B/Test.py", line 1, in <module> from ..A import Account

ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

Comment: You really should mention your Python version when asking about features which have changed radically between versions (relative imports, Unicode, and a few others). Sometimes people will be able to guess based on the specific error you got, or how you wrote your code, but you shouldn't count on people guessing right.

Comment: Give this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70395407/import-module-from-a-sibling-directory-in-python3-10/73081295#73081295) a try. It worked for me

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is happening because `A` and `B` are independent, unrelated, packages as far as Python is concerned.

Create a `__init__.py` in the same directory as `Driver.py` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the __init__.py files a little bit? I have not understood explanations found online. I come from a c++ background, so I am used to just giving the path for includes and such

Comment: It's a bit hand-wavy, but basically: putting a `__init__.py` file in a directory means "in this directory, all of the `.py` files, and all of the subdirectories which contain a `__init__.py` file, are part of the same package".

Comment: All he needs if from A import Account in driver.py. Adding the extra init.py and using a relative import is a bit awkward and pollutes the toplevel.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me using Python 2.7.14. I assume the solution is for Python 3.x? Is there a python2 solution for those forced to work in legacy systems?

Comment: @retsigam This works for both Python 2 & Python 3.  In fact, this syntax was created for Python 2.3 or 2.4 or something like that (I forget the release time).

Comment: While @DavidWolever is 100% right, the [preferred style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports) is to use a full import once you've done those `__init__.py` tricks.  E.g., `from <toplevel>.A import Account`.

Comment: I created an `__init__.py` and I'm still getting the same error. I'm on Python 3.7. What gives?

Comment: I use 3.6.8 and I need `Test.py` to read `from A import account`. Then, I can call `Driver.py` from its containing directory.

Comment: If nothing here is working for you, I recommend reading the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time. It explains how relative imports work and helped me understand at least why my imports weren't working.

Answer (score 17):

In my case adding `__init__.py` was not enough. You also have to append the path of the parent directory if you get module not found error.

```
root :
 |
 |__SiblingA:
 |    \__A.py
 |     
 |__SiblingB:
 |      \_ __init__.py
 |      \__B.py
 |
```

To import B.py from A.py, you have to do the following

```
import sys
  
# append the path of the parent directory
sys.path.append("..")

from SiblingB import B
print("B is successfully imported!")
```

Comment: This worked best for me in August 2022.   This should be the accepted answer!   The accepted answer does not provide the full directory structure and code for this to work.

Comment: It does not working for me. But works with only a dot `sys.path.append(".")`

Comment: Amazing that I had to search for hours for an answer to a very common problem that has frustrated so many people, when it should be easily found in the docs, and also that the solution is so relatively complicated for something that comes up so often. I thought simple is better than complex?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

is that `A` is the same directory level as `Driver.py`. Hence, `..A` in `from ..A import Account` is beyond top-level package.

You can solve this by create a new folder named `AandB` together with `__init__py` in this new folder, and then move `A` and `B` folders into `AandB` folder. The directory structure is as following：

[image: The directory structure]

Correspondingly, the content in `Driver.py` should be modified as `from AandB.B import Test`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, and it does not requires calling `sys.path.append("..") `