# Can't import module from sibling directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a Python 3 project that's structured like this:

```
/project
    __init__.py
    /models
        __init__.py
        my_model.py
        base_model.py
    /tests
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

In `test.py` I want to import `my_model`. My first attempt was `from models import my_model`, which threw an `ImportError: No module named 'models'`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/python-import-module-from-sibling-folder) recommended adding an `__init__.py` file to each directory, which didn't help. [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446075/676001) said to modify the path with:

```
import sys; import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

but this throws an error when `my_model` tries to import from `base_model`.

This seems really straightforward but I'm stumped. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute imports everywhere: `from project.models import my_model`, should work fine from wherever in your project, no need to mess with paths either.

Comment: I'm still getting the same `ImportError` when I import from `project.models`. I triple-checked that the root folder has `__init__.py` and everything.

Comment: Does ``tests/`` have an ``__init__.py`` as well? I now notice it was missing in your listing.

Comment: Although I kinda promised no messing with paths, the parent of your project directory should be in your ``$PYTHONPATH`` (or ``sys.path.insert()``it)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the sibling directory to `sys.path` should work:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../models'))
import my_model
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you launch test.py.
The only way I know to do relative imports is to have the file in a package. For the Python interpreter to know you're in a package is to import it in some way.

Use:

```
from ..models import my_model
```

in test.py

And launch the Python Interpreter below the project folder.

You will then be able to import project.tests.test without error.

Comment: I'm launching test.py directly from the command line. When I try `from ..models import my_model` it gives me an error `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`. I made sure the root directory has an `__init__.py` file.