# Importing modules from sibling of parent folder

Tags: python, python-import

I am working on a project which has a structure similar to

```
project
│   README.md
│
└───package1
│    │  __init__.py
│    │  moduleA.py
│    │  └───classX
│    │  └───classY
│    │  moduleB.py
│
└───package2
│    │  __init__.py
│    │  moduleC.py
│    │  moduleD.py
│
└───package3
│   │   __init__.py
│   │   moduleE.py
│   │   moduleF.py
│   │
│   └───subpackage31
│       │   __init__.py
│       │   moduleG.py
│       │   moduleH.py
```

Inside `moduleG`, I am trying to import `moduleC`, as well as classes `X` and `Y` defined inside `moduleA`. I tried,

```
from ...package2 import moduleC
from ...package1.moduleA import classX
```

I get the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project/package3/subpackage31/moduleG.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ...package2 import moduleC
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do relative imports outside a package.  You would need to add an `__init__.py` at the top level to make `project` a package.

Comment: Also it should be 2 dots `..package2` not three `...package2`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but Google brought me here and I thought I would share a possible solution. You could do the following:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from package2 import moduleC
from package1.moduleA import classX
```

Comment: for the people that still cannot make it work, it is solved by adding an intermediate folder containing both siblings https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114877/9404261