# Python3 Importing module/package from sibling directories

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

Here is my code directory structure:

```
/root
-/proj1
--/module1.py
--/__init__.py
--/sub_proj1
---/module2.py
---/__init__.py
-/proj2
--/module3.py
```

If I want to import code from module2.py into module3.py I tried the following import statement:

```
from .proj1.sub_proj1 import *
```

but I am getting import error.  Is thee anything I need to fix?  I am not sure what I am doing wrong with relative imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to this question:

[Python import module from sibling folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/python-import-module-from-sibling-folder)

You need an `__init__.py` in your root and both project folders

Also this should be your import statement:

```
from ..proj1.sub_proj1 import *
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  If I were to add the __init__.py and have another folder in root as "proj3" and don't want anything in there imported, do I do just make sure that there is no __init__.py inside "proj3"?