# How I can Import from a other relative folder wihout the knowledge of the path?

Tags: python, import, pygame, python-import, python-3.7

I am working on a little video game in Pygame. I want it to be very clear in the folder hierarchy, so, I've already prepare it in this way :

```
Python 
   Project 
      bin
        init.py
        Project.vbs
      lib
        constants.py
        definitions.py
      sprites ( useless for topic )
      Project.exe
```

The Project.exe is a ink file, a fake executable. In fact, it's a shortcut to the Project.vbs with open the init.py (It's just for have the clearest folder managment).

What is my problem?
I want to import the difinitions.py and the constants.py from the init.py which is in 'bin' folder, it's just absolutely critical for the game.
By The way, the files are saved on my USB key but the path of this one always change:

On my own computer, it's `C:/user/Save19/Python/...`

On my high school computers, it's `P:/documents/Python` ( internship )

On my phone it's `/storage/0/Python/...`

And anytime I made a copy, the path change...

So I've read a lot of topics for try to fix that but anytime it's not working :/

I've try it by using :

`Import constants from lib import constants from lib.definitions import *`
I've try ths with the os and the path

`import sys sys.path.insert(0, 'Project/lib') import constants`

`import sys sys.path.append('Project/lib') import constants`

But it not working anyway... Can somebody give me a solution and explain me it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 Importing module/package from sibling directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225775/python3-importing-module-package-from-sibling-directories)

Comment: No, it isn't because I've already try to add somes '__init.py__' to all the folders and still not working...

Comment: after adding the init files, have you tried it with the relative import as mentioned in the answer there?

Comment: It's said  'constant' molude not existing...

Comment: check spelling. constants???

Comment: @Edhyjox: *"to import `*.py` from the `init.py` which is in `bin` folder"*: The name should be `__init__.py` and should be placed in `lib`. Your `sys.path.append('Project/lib')` should be `sys.path.append('./lib')`

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Yeah, It's just a mistake in my answer xD

Comment: @stovfl It's continu to said me   `line 9, in <module> import constants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constant'`

Comment: @Edhyjox: I use relative path, is your `cwd == Python/Project`?

Comment: @stovfl Wait, what is cwd ?

Comment: @Edhyjox: Current Working Directory

Comment: Yes, it's that ( there is only two others files that I haven't mentioned ( 1st named 'Font', and second named 'sprites' with respectively somes custom fonts and all the picture I need )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends from where you're starting the Python process. Whatever path you're adding should be relative to that location. So you say it's started from within `bin` and so you can add

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../lib'))
import constants
```

You can also add `__init__.py` to `lib` and then add `".."` to path and do `import lib.constants as constants`.

Or you can setup and install the whole thing as a Python package and then use absolute imports such as `import mygame.lib.constants as constants`.

Comment: Thank a lot : Working with 
`import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../lib'))
import constants`

Comment: Please vote for my question if this one help you, It's help me to won some reputation ! :D