# python import from sibling folder

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module from a python file that is in a sibling folder. I read several similar questions here and tried to apply solutions listed there, but I wasn't able to solve the problem.

The structure is as follows:

```
parentfolder/gfolder/codefolder/fileA.py
parentfolder/gfolder/utilfolder/util.py
```

`gfolder`, `codefolder` and `utilfolder` all have an `__init__.py`.

I'm trying to do in fileA.py:

```
import gfolder.utilfolder.util as util
```

I also tried adding before the import statement:

```
sys.path.append(".../parentfolder/")
```

And that didn't work either:

```
import gfolder.utilfolder.util as util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gfolder'
```

The solution in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/python-import-module-from-sibling-folder) says to include `__init.py__` in the directories, which I already have.

**EDIT**:
Now both `sys.append` and `sys.insert` work and the problem was that I included a slash at the end of the path. When I took it out, everything worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import module from sibling folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/python-import-module-from-sibling-folder)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me describe you the differences between a **Python module** & a **Python package** so that both of us are on the same page. ✌

---

#### A module is **a single .py file (or files)** that are imported under one import and used. ✔

`import aModuleName 
 # Here 'aModuleName' is just a regular .py file.`

#### Whereas, a package is a **collection of modules** in directories that give a package hierarchy. A package contains a distinct **`__init__.py`** file. ✔

`` from aPackageName import aModuleName
 # Here 'aPackageName` is a folder with a `__init__.py` file
 # and 'aModuleName', which is just a regular .py file. ``

---

Therefore, when we have a project directory named **proj-dir** of the following structure  ⤵

`proj-dir
 --|--__init__.py
   --package1
     --|--__init__.py
     --|--module1.py
   --package2
     --|--__init__.py
     --|--module2.py`

> Notice that I've also added an empty **`__init__.py`** into the **proj-dir** itself which makes it a package too.

Now, if you want to import any python object from **module2** of **package2** into **module1** of **package1**, then the **import** statement in the file **module1.py** would be

`from proj-dir.package2.module2 import object2
 # if you were to import the entire module2 then,
 from proj-dir.package2 import module2`

#### I hope this simple explanation clarifies your doubts on Python imports' mechanism.

Comment: Hi @Sushant Chaudhary, I have a question will this work if the script runs from package1 module1?

I am trying it and it seems to me that pythons imports will only work if called from a file that is above all imports.

E.g in this example I would need a main.py in Proj-dir if this main.py is my entry point all imports will work but if I run package2 module2 directly I will get a "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

is this how it works?

Comment: It actually doesn't work this way, your parent package does not appear in sys.path automatically. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports/50193944#50193944

Comment: This answer **does not work** if you call the script (module) directly, you must use `python -m project.package1.module1` instead.

Comment: With the equivalent layout `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named proj-dir` is raised

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Cox answerd int the following thread [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path)

You can add the subdirectory to your Python path so that it imports as a normal script

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, <path to gfolder>)
import gfolder
```

you can also add the directory to the PATH var of the Linux system (I use it while I'm working on a project, at the end i modified the PATH to it's origin value)

if you maintain the following structre than it is working out side the box

```
parentfolder/gfolder/codefolder/fileA.py
parentfolder/gfolder/utilfolder/util.py
parentfolder/gfolder/main.py
```

run main.py