# Can't import module from another folder in Python

Tags: python, import

So, I've tried a lot of things from the Internet, but nothing helps me. I have main.py file and I have a neighbour folder 'A' and folder 'B' in 'A'. How can I import .py files from 'B' to main.py? P.S I've tested variant about **init**.py, but it causes unresolved import error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python import module from sibling folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/python-import-module-from-sibling-folder)

Comment: Duplicate. Here is one way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folder `A` and `B` should have empty `__init__.py` files in it. More about this in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

[image]

*a_file.py*

```
def im_a_function():
    print("Printing from A folder function")
```

*b_file.py*

```
from A.a_file import im_a_function

def im_b_function():
    im_a_function()
```

*main.py*

```
from B.b_file import im_b_function

im_b_function()
```

running *main.py* file will print out message `Printing from A folder function`