# ModuleNotFoundError error when running script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have examined many questions that have been asked before but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm running **python3 folder1/script1.py** command on the terminal in the root directory
but I get the error **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'**.
I added *__ init __.py* to the folders but still couldn't find a solution.

My project directory is like this:

```
└── root
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── script1.py
    │   
    └── folder2
        ├── module1.py
```

module1.py:

```
def say_hello():
    print('hello')
```

scipt1.py:

```
from folder2 import module1

module1.say_hello()
```

[image]

Comment: See this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/how-to-import-a-python-module-from-a-sibling-folder

Comment: I tried this. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, python modules need to be installed for python to find them. One side rule is that python will look in a script's path to see if the module is there. Move `script1.py` down a level, make sure you have an `__init__.py` and it will work.

```
└── root
    ├── script1.py
    │   
    └── folder2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1.py
```

You could also have `script1.py` insert its grandparent directory into `sys.path`. But really the best way to solve the problem is to make the package installable by adding a setup.py. An extremely primitive version is

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="Foobar",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    scripts=["folder1/script1.py"]
)
```

and your directory can be

```
└── root
    ├── setup.py
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── script1.py
    │   
    └── folder2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module1.py
```

Now you can do `python setup.py develop` to run your script from your development directory. Or `python setup.py install` (frequently in a venv you created) to make it a standard install.

Answer (score 0):

Right usage for init with double underscores;

```
__init__
```

> I added _ init _.py to the folders but still couldn't find a solution.

You write init with just one.

Comment: I added empty init files. But this isn't  the solution.