# Python - package in parallel directory not found from *behave* test

Tags: python, module, package, behavior

I'm trying to get a [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) test done in Python.

A simple behave test per se is no problem. But I'm struggling as soon as I try to use a module from a package I've already created and which is in a parallel directory.

The directory structure is something like:

```
src
 ├── connection
 │    │
 │    └── api_connector.py
 │
 ├── behave_tests
 │    │
 │    ├─ steps
 │    │  │
 │    │  └ testCommands.py
 │    │
 │    ├── testConnection.feature
 │    └── testCommands.feature
 │
 └── unit_tests
```

Normally, **behave** is started from inside the *behave_tests* directory. And at first, it run fine. All Python code for the behave test was in the file *testCommands.py*, only packages from the python core were used.

But then I changed *testCommands.py* to use code from my own package *connection* which is tested and working.

In *testCommands.py* I wrote the input line

```
from connection.api_connector import ApiConnector, SerialApiConnector
```

But this input line isn't resolved by behave, it outputs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connection'
```

I tried to append my package *connection* to the python module path by adding the following lines to the top of *test_commands.py*

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/username/projects/projectname/src/connection/')
```

But it didn't help.

How can I tell **behave** to use my *connection* package?

Comment: Similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886143/how-to-import-a-python-module-from-a-sibling-folder

Answer (score 0):

After some further reading I was able to find the solution.

1. To make Python recognize the directory *connection* as a package I had to add empty `__init__.py` files into both directories: *src* and *connection*.
2. To be able to address the package *connection* using absolute imports, the *PYTHONPATH* environment variable must point into the *src* directory.

E.g. in a linux shell I set PYTHONPATH by typing

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/{username}/test_project/src
```

Then the python interpreter and also **behave** find and resolve the module in question as long as they are started from within this shell.