# How do I import a module found in a sibling directory?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following file structure below. From the root, I want to run **A.py** which will import functions in **B.py**. How do I load a module found in a sibling directory?

```
root :
 |
 |__SiblingA:
 |    \__A.py
 |     
 |__SiblingB:
 |      \__B.py
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sibling package imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323860/sibling-package-imports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, lets say you want to import a function named as `create` from `SiblingB/B.py`

To import the `create` function from a file named `B.py` located inside a sibling directory named `SiblingB` one directory above the current file, you can use the following code:

```
from ..SiblingB.B import create
```

This uses the `from ..` syntax to move one directory above the current location, then specifies the path to the `SiblingB` directory, and finally imports the `create` function from the `B.py` file inside that directory.

Please note that this code assumes that the `SiblingB` directory is a valid package with a proper `__init__.py` file, and that the `B.py` file is located within that package.

Comment: doesn't works for me, but this solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72114877/9404261